# What is the most efficient way to make sure there are no duplicates in an array?

Tags: gas

Is a nested for loop (like below) the best and most gas efficient way to make sure there are no duplicates in say an array of addresses? I can't think of a better one but it seems very inefficient

```
for(i=0, i<array.length -1, i++) {
    for(j=0, j<array.length, j++) {
        if(array[i] == array[j]) {
           revert DuplicatesNotAllowed()}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: since this is an artificial problem, I recommend adding an in-memory mapping that tracks which addresses have already been seen, and revert if such an address is encountered:

```
error DuplicatesNotAllowed();

mapping(address => bool) seen;

function test(address[] calldata array) external {
    uint i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (seen[array[i]]) {
            revert DuplicatesNotAllowed();
        }
        seen[array[i]] = true;
    }
}
```

The traditional answer is to sort the array (O(n logn) complexity) and then make a pass over the array to look for duplicates in a single pass (O(n) complexity).

However, in a smart contract programming language, the fact that you even need to ask this question indicates that something is very wrong. First of all, array is usually not the right data structure, mappings or merkle trees are usually better. Especially arrays that can reach unlimited size is a no-go, because trying to loop over such an array can cause to run out of gas, so an attacker can cause denial of service (DoS) by packing the array with fake entries.

Comment: Thank you... This is a smart contract auditing exercise so I think it's designed to have some flaws.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to repeatedly check that an iterable collection doesn't have duplicates, it's better to use a custom data structure to enable this.

For example, an enumerable set will let you iterate while ensuring it has no duplicates, e.g. [OpenZeppelin version](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol).  The order of iteration is not guaranteed, however.